# Append to list in a dictionary after setdefault

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have the below code where I am trying to append a 1 to the hash of an element, on every occurence of it in input.

```
def test(Ar):
    hash_table = {}
    for elem in Ar:
        if elem not in hash_table:
            hash_table.setdefault(elem,[]).append(1)
        else:
            hash_table[elem] = hash_table[elem].append(1)
    print(hash_table)

Ar = (1,2,3,4,5,1,2)
test(Ar)
```

Output:

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: [1], 4: [1], 5: [1]}
```

Expected Output:

```
{1: [1,1], 2: [1,1], 3: [1], 4: [1], 5: [1]}
```

I am puzzled why None gets in on doing an append. Kindly explain what is happening.

Note:

On typing the else portion,

```
hash_table[elem] = hash_table[elem].append(1) # the append() was not suggested at all by the IDE. I forcibly put it, hoping things will work.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `list.append` is an in-place operation. So it just modifies the list object and doesn't return anything. That is why, by default, `None` is getting returned from `list.append` and you are storing that corresponding to the key in this line

```
hash_table[elem] = hash_table[elem].append(1)
```

---

In your case, you don't need the `if` condition at all.

```
def test(Ar):
    hash_table = {}
    for elem in Ar:
        hash_table.setdefault(elem, []).append(1)
    print(hash_table)
```

because, `setdefault` will first look for the key `elem` in it and it found something, then it will return the value corresponding to it. And if it doesn't then it will create key `elem` and use the second argument passed to it as the value and then return then value.

---

Instead of using this, you can use `collections.defaultdict`, like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
def test(Ar):
    hash_table = defaultdict(list)
    for elem in Ar:
        hash_table[elem].append(1)
    print(hash_table)
```

This would do almost the same thing as the `setdefault` version

---

It looks like you are trying to find the frequency of elements. In that case you can simply use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
Ar = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2)
print Counter(Ar)
# Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

This will give the number of times each and every element occurred in the iterable passed.

Comment: Also note that `defaultdict` have a `default_factory` property, which when set to `None` makes the default dict behave like a regular dict once again.  This is particularly useful for functions which want to construct a dictionary using defaultdict behaviors, but then want to return something that behaves like a regular dict.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in this line:

```
hash_table[elem] = hash_table[elem].append(1)
```

`list.append(x)` returns `None`, which you are assigning to `hash_table[elem]`

The `else` part is unnecessary, but still for getting correct results, remove the assignment in the `else` part.

---

Note that the `None` is only for elements that occur twice. If any element existed thrice, you'd have gotten an error.